# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined useEffect hook with redux async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to learn the use of React-Redux with axios asynchronous method, and I use the `useEffect` hook to call the async function and dispatch the action to store and assign the data to the state, however I am unable to get the state after running. I did get the data from API, which just did not assign to the `channel` state, and does not render.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import counterReducer from './modules/counterStore';
import channelReducer from './modules/channelStore';

// create store with reducer
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    channel: channelReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const channelStore = createSlice({
  name: "channelStore",
  initialState: {
    channel: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setChannel: (state, action) => {
      state.channel = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

const { setChannel } = channelStore.actions;
const channelReducer = channelStore.reducer;

const fetchChannelList = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    await axios.get("http://geek.itheima.net/v1_0/channels").then(
      (res) => {
        dispatch(setChannel(res.data.data.channels))
        console.log(res.data.data.channels)
      }
    );
  };
}

export { fetchChannelList };
export default channelReducer;
```

```
import './App.css';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchChannelList } from './store/modules/channelStore';

function App() {
  const { channelList } = useSelector(state => state.channel)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchChannelList())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <div >
      <ul>
        {channelList?.map(item => {
          return (<li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

I was trying to fetch the data from api and use dispatch action to assign the data to the the state and render in the page.

Comment: Is the only place you use `.map()` in your app in your JSX `channelList?.map(item => {`. This shouldn't ever give you that error, considering you're using optional chaining here. Perhaps the error is actually coming from somewhere else in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Probable Issue

You are setting a `channel` state but the UI is attempting to destructure some `channelList` property from the selected `state.channel` which is an an object with only a `channel` property that is an array.

```js
const channelStore = createSlice({
  name: "channelStore",
  initialState: {
    channel: [], // <-- array
  },
  reducers: {
    setChannel: (state, action) => {
      state.channel = action.payload; // <-- array
    },
  },
});

const fetchChannelList = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    await axios.get("http://geek.itheima.net/v1_0/channels").then(
      (res) => {
        dispatch(setChannel(res.data.data.channels)) // <-- array
        console.log(res.data.data.channels)
      }
    );
  };
}
```

```
const {
  channelList // <-- undefined property
} = useSelector(state => state.channel) // <-- channel state, e.g. { channel }

...

{channelList?.map(item => {
  return (
    <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
  )
})}
```

The error *shouldn't* happen in the code example you provided since you are using the Optional Chaining operator on `channelList`, but perhaps this is not the case in your actual code. Either way, `channelList` is incorrect for the state you are maintaining.

## Solution

Select the correct state. `state.channel.channel` is the array the `channelStore` slice it maintaining.

```
const channel = useSelector(state => state.channel.channel);

...

{channel.map(item => (
  <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
))}
```